# Java Api Speechmatics

Tags: java

The below code is used to connect to the speechmatics api for conversion of speech to text in java. But unable to connect and gives back an error.
https://app.speechmatics.com/api-details
Here is the link which contains the total information and im using this :

curl -F data_file=@my_audio_file.mp3 -F model=en-US "https://api.speechmatics.com/v1.0/user/$MY_API_USER_ID/jobs/?auth_token=$MY_API_AUTH_TOKEN" # transcription

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.speechmatics.com/v1.0/user/17879/jobs/?auth_token=ZmQzODNiMGUtMzQwYS00MzUxLWJkZDEtZTBlYzUxMTg2YWVm");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("model", "en-US");
        conn.setRequestProperty("data_file", "open('RecordAudio.wav', 'rb')");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "2:5a703eadae214b0bbe91344e546eac4a");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
          // s= s.concat(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The code below will request a transcription using a post request.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.File;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello");
        try {
            URI uri = new URIBuilder("https://api.speechmatics.com/v1.0/user/$user_id/jobs/")
                    .addParameter("auth_token", "$auth_token")
                    .build();

            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
            httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            File imgFile = new File("/filepath/test_short.aac");

            HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .addTextBody("model", "en-US")
                .addTextBody("notification", "none")
                .addBinaryBody("data_file", imgFile, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY ,imgFile.getName())
                .build();

            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            //System.out.println(entity.getContent());
            System.out.println("Executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            System.out.println(response);
            httpclient.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```