# how to get the transcript text from speechMatics

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, speech-to-text, transcription

I am working on a `java` transcript video app and I've used `speechMatics` to transcript my video.  How do I get the transcripted text from `speechMatics`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What format is your "trascripted text" in?  Do you have any code you can share?

Comment: I've already used a post method to transcript my audio and now my transcript text appears  on my  speechmatics dashboard and i dont know how to download it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell you have already used a POST to upload your video, so now simply use a GET request to download it.

Please refer to the API: https://app.speechmatics.com/api-details

Specifically the section on getting a transcript that shows how you need to form the GET request: https://app.speechmatics.com/api-details#getTranscript

> GET transcript file for a particular transcription job.
>
> ```
> curl "https://api.speechmatics.com/v1.0/user/$MY_API_USER_ID/jobs/$MY_JOB_ID/transcript?auth_token=$MY_API_AUTH_TOKEN"
> ```

The above will return a JSON file of your transcript, but you can also get a plain text file by adding `format=txt` to your request like so:

> ```
> curl "https://api.speechmatics.com/v1.0/user/$MY_API_USER_ID/jobs/$MY_JOB_ID/transcript?format=txt&auth_token=$MY_API_AUTH_TOKEN"
> ```

You obviously need an API_User and a JOB_ID, but these can be obtained when you upload the video, or if you do not know the JOB_ID then you can get a list of all jobs and find the key you need from the list:

> ```
> curl "https://api.speechmatics.com/v1.0/user/$MY_API_USER_ID/jobs/?auth_token=$MY_API_AUTH_TOKEN"
> ```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464332/java-api-speechmatics

Answer (score -1):

donno how to get my jobId  of the transcript text

Comment: This cannot be accepted as an answer post.